# Ближайшая точка среди 4 объектов

Tags: координаты

Есть координатная ось, на ней расположены 4 объекта`(A,B,C,D)`,и одна точка `Т`.Надо найти самую ближайшую точку среди этих 4 объектов по x и по y(надо просто координаты), тоесть где должна находится точчка T,чтобы находится на самом выгодном месте.

Координаты точек:

```
B[-100;200]
C[100;250]
D[200;50]
```

Спасибо заранее!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Таки что мы минимизируем? Сумму расстояний от Т до А, Б, Ц и Д?

Comment: просто координаты точки Т, которая будет выгоднее всего стоять от точек A,B,C,D

Comment: Я пытаюсь выяснить у вас что вы понимаете под словом «выгоднее»

Comment: Под словом выгоднее, чтобы он стоял на самом ближайшем месте от всех точек одновременно

Comment: А как узнать что T1 выгоднее T2? Есть какая-то процедура?

Comment: Предлагаю точку Т[0;0]. Очень выгодная, ничего считать не нужно.